# Is Lazy<T> a good solution for a thread safe lazy loaded singleton?

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

We implemented a lazy loaded singleton using double locking on get to make sure the instance is only initialized once (and not twice due to thread race conditions).

I was wondering if simply using `Lazy<T>` is a good solution for this problem?

I.E.

```
private static Lazy<MyClass> _instance = new Lazy<MyClass>(() => return new MyClass());

public static MyClass Instance
{
    get
    {
        return _instance.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely, yes. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Of course. Good article from Jon Skit on the topic: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest you to read referenced articles from comments:

- [Lazy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx)
- [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

In all cases the `Lazy<T>` class is thread-safe, but you need to remember that the `Value` of this type can be thread-unsafe, and can be corrupted in multithreading environment:

```
private static Lazy<MyClass> _instance = new Lazy<MyClass>(() => return new MyClass());

public static MyClass Instance
{
   get {
      return _instance.Value;
   }
}

public void MyConsumerMethod()
{
    lock (Instance)
    {
        // this is safe usage
        Instance.SomeMethod();
    }

    // this can be unsafe operation
    Instance.SomeMethod();
}
```

Also you can use [any constructor you like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642318.aspx) depending on the environment of your application.