# How can I make this c# property thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have the following code in c# code which computes a property value:

```
    public class Options
    {
        public bool UseFeature
        {
            public bool NoUseFeatureInternal { get; set; }
            public bool UseFeatureInternal { get; set; }
            get
            {
                // Command line param
                if (NoUseFeatureInternal )
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // Command line param
                if (UseFeatureInternal )
                {
                    return true;
                }

                if (cachedUseFeature.HasValue)
                {
                    return cachedUseFeature.Value;
                }

                string userName= Override.GetUserName();
                cachedUseFeature = ToolBox.Config.Flights.IsActive("FeatureName", overrideName);

                return cachedUseFeature.Value;
            }
        }

        private bool? cachedUseFeature;
    }

    public static class ToolBox
    {
        private static Lazy<GlobalConfig> configLazy = new Lazy<GlobalConfig>(() => GlobalConfig.Load() ?? GlobalConfig.Default);

        public static GlobalConfigConfig
        {
            get
            {
                return configLazy.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class GlobalConfig
    {
        public static GlobalConfig Load(string filePath = null)
        {
            filePath = filePath ?? GetGlobalConfigPath();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath) || !File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                return null;
            }

            string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            // Parses json
            return ParseConfig(fileContents);
        }
    }
```

I access Options.UseFeature value from multiple tasks.  I seem to have some parts of the program where the values comes out to true, and some where it turns out be false, but only some of the time.  My thought process is that I know that due to the multiple threads,  `cachedUseFeature = ToolBox.Config.Flights.IsActive("UseFeature", overrideName);` could be called multiple times.  However, I don't see how it could give different answers at the various times it is called.  Would a lazy value for cachedUseFeature solve this, or is there something else going on?  Looking at [Is Lazy<T> a good solution for a thread safe lazy loaded singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076233/is-lazyt-a-good-solution-for-a-thread-safe-lazy-loaded-singleton), I am tempted to put a lock around Toolbox.Config everywhere it is used, but I'm not sure that is the correct solution either.

Comment: I believe something else is going on your program. Once GlobalConfig is loaded then, the value should not vary.

Comment: Lazy<T> is thread safe, sorry - the issue must be somewhere else. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

You could make Options a singleton and execute the following line in the private constructor of the singleton

```
cachedUseFeature = ToolBox.Config.Flights.IsActive("UseFeature", overrideName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mutex synchronisation is usually done via a lock block.

1. add a dedicate Object to lock onto. Something private that nobody else can see. **Never** try to lock on something you are giving out.
2. Wrap all code that needs mutual exclusion into a lock block.
3. This does mean you would ahve to code out every get and set function. So no more auto-implement properties. I know of no Syntax Sugar that will get you around that.

   ```
   private object mutex = new object();
   public bool UseFeatureInternal {
     get {
        lock(mutex){
          //put all get code - including return statements - into this block
        }
     }
     set {
        lock(mutex){
          //put all set code here
        }
     }
   }
   ```

But as others pointed out, this might not actually be the droid you are looking for.